# В выдаче в поиске Google показываютя ссылки вопреки запрету в robots

Tags: поиск, robots.txt

Сделал запрет в роботс на индексацию некоторых страниц сайта, вот:

```
User-agent: *

Disallow: /coupon-categories/*
Disallow: /coupon-tags/*
Disallow: /coupon-tags/
Disallow: /coupon-categories/
```

Но при добавлении в wordpress новых тегов и категорий, вопреки запрета в роботс, в выдачи показывает страницы mysite.net/coupon-tags/electronics/ и другие..
Почему так происходит?

Comment: Проверьте включены ли эти ссылки в sitemap.xml. их там не должно быть. Эти ссылки роботы в обход роботс.тхт могут обрабатывать

Comment: та я sitemap.xml не добавлял в google webmasters

Comment: Это и не обязательно. Он автоматом проверяется...

Answer (score 1):

В robots.txt пишутся правила для тех роботов,которые их соблюдают, но есть и такие роботы, которые не соблюдают данные правила. Возможно причина именно в этом. Также, проверьте на сервере как называется Ваш robots.txt. Должен называться так  - robots.txt.